# JSON map object to the table in React

Tags: json, reactjs, object

I have a JSON that is coming like this and I want to show this JSON in the table in React.

```
{
  "Status": true, 
  "discounts": { 
    "individual": {
      "number_of_cars_discount": {
        "1": "1", 
        "10": "1", 
        "2": "0.98", 
      }
    }
  }, 
  "main_price": {
    "client_type": "individual", 
    "large_car": {
      "100": "3", 
      "1000": "0.9", 
      "100000": "0.60", 
    }, 
  }
}
```

So to do this, I defined

```
const [mainPrice, setMainPrice] = useState({});
```

in the parent component and I fetched it like this:

```
setMainPrice(res.data.main_price);
```

I sent the mainPrice to the child component where I want to display JSON in the table:

```
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
            {Object.keys(individualPosts).map((key) => (
              <tr>
                <td key={key}>{individualPosts[key]}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
            </td>
            <td>
            {Object.keys(mainPrice.large_car).map((key) => (
              <tr>
                <td key={key}>{mainPrice.large_car[key]}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

But it gives me an error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

But I couldnt figure out why.

I have other types of cars like large_cars, small_cars so I need to take the mainPrice like this. I don't want to define all the types of cars and send them to the child component as a props. Or should I make it like this?

Please give me advice and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Null check required in such cases to avoid errors.

Try this

```
<td>
  {Object.keys(mainPrice?.large_car).length > 0 && Object.keys(mainPrice?.large_car).map((key) => (
   <tr>
    <td key={key}>{mainPrice.large_car[key]}</td>
   </tr>
  ))}
</td>
```

Comment: I am getting TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object but the thing is mainPrice is not null